# Need to add "directions to here" link in infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to both Google Maps and Javascript but have to get this issue solved! I have an .html file with a google map of our client's location loaded into the map_canvas div. Through tutorials, I have been able to figure out how to write enough Javascript to get the map to function, have a custom marker and and infowindow that pops up when you click on it. The only part left is to have a link inside the infowindow that says "directions to here" and there's a text field that the user can type in their starting address. I'm seeing plenty of documentation to help me write my own code on the Google Developer's site but I am  not advanced enough to do this. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.929011, -84.361);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.929011, -84.361),
        map: map,
        title: 'Atlanta/Sandy Springs',
        clickable: true,
        icon: 'images/mapmarker.png'
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'client address'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: Please indent your code when pasting here -> it's easier to read it and help (Corrected it for you).

Comment: Like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4.html)? (from here/to here in the infowindow, translated from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial, throws the request to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com))

Comment: Or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4c.html)? from here/to here in the infowindow, translated from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial, uses the v3 directions service)

Answer (score 4):

There are several pieces I added. First, you need a better HTML form inside the infowindow, since I only put in the basic parts and it won't respond when you press Enter.

Next, I added a geocoder because the directions Service won't take "human readable" addresses, only latLng coordinates. The geocoder converts the two. Finally, the directions Service and Display are added. The directions text goes into a div (directionsPanel).

See the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haG2S/) or use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
  html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%
  }
  #map_canvas {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%
  }
  #directionsPanel {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      width: 50%
  }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var directionsService;
var directionsDisplay;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.929011, -84.361);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.929011, -84.361),
        map: map,
        title: 'Atlanta/Sandy Springs',
        clickable: true
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Your address: <input id='clientAddress' type='text'>"+
                "<input type='button' onClick=getDir() value='Go!'>"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: false
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
}

function getDir() {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': document.getElementById('clientAddress').value
    },

    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var origin = results[0].geometry.location;
            var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(33.929011, -84.361);

            var request = {
                origin: origin,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

        } else {
            document.getElementById('clientAddress').value =
                "Directions cannot be computed at this time.";
        }
    });
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="directionsPanel"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I created a fiddle to try out your solution, but it doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/haG2S/

Comment: @Jeromy French, There were 2 small typos on the code: Line 18, remove coma after "true". Lines 22 and 23: Add "+ at the end of line 22 and add the opening " on line 23. I modified you fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/haG2S/2/)

Comment: So there was one last detail for @Heitor Chang's to work on jsfiddle: You need to make sure the Fiddle options are on "No Wrap - in <body>. See here [updated and working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haG2S/4/)

Comment: @pascal: thanks, that works now. I can't award the bounty to your comment--can you create an answer from your comments?

Comment: Glad it works, however I think @HeitorChang should get the Bounty since he did the work :) You can just vote up the comment with the link to the Fiddle.